# Complejidad del MergeSort

Tags: algoritmos, ordenamiento, optimización, complejidad

Tengo una duda respecto al algoritmo de ordenamiento **Mergesort**.

He visto en algunos foros que la complejidad es `O(nlog(n))`, pero en otros dicen que es `O(nlog2(n))` (logaritmo de n en base 2). En algunos videos también veo que dicen lo mismo: unos dicen que es el primero, pero otros dicen que es el segundo. Por lo que me genera confusión. ¿Me podrían explicar?

Comment: Es lo mismo, O(nlog(n)) es lo mismo que O(nlog2(n))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extendiendo el comentario de @Japv. Cuando trabajamos con la notación "O grande" (Big O) la base en la que se encuentre el logaritmo es indiferente, ya que el resultado siempre va a ser el mismo, por lo tanto se cumple lo siguiente:

```
O(log2 N) = O(log10 N) = O(loge N)
```

Esto se debe a las propiedades de los logaritmos y a que la notacion "O grande" hace que todos lo logaritmos en diferentes bases **estén relacionados por un factor constante**, por lo tanto se puede transformar la base del logaritmo de dos a diez o a "N" y el resultado seguirá siendo el mismo.

[Documentación sobre logaritmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)

Comment: Mucha gracias. Ya logré entender más por la documentación y tu explicación.